# Sub-array using $p$ commas

Tags: r, arrays, sub-array, array-indexing

Say I have an array Y of size (n x m_1 x m_2 x m_3). If I want the first sub-array of size (m_1 x m_2 x m_3) I can choose it using commas as

```
Y(1,,,)
```

Similarly, if Y is of size (n x m_1 x m_2 x m_3 x m_4) and I want the first sub-array of size (m_1 x m_2 x m_3 x m_4), I can choose it using commas as

```
Y(1,,,,)
```

In general, if Y is an array of size (n x m_1 x m_2 x ... x m_p) and I want the first sub-array of size (m_1 x m_2 x ... x m_p), I can choose it as

```
Y(1,,...,)
```

where ,,..., means p different commas. If p is known, how can I write the p commas?

A simple solution is

```
array(array(Y,c(dim(Y)[1],prod(dim(Y)[-1])))[1,])
```

However, this is inefficient code (Y is potentially massive, and I prefer not to transform it to a matrix to then transform it back to an array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always build an expression as text and evaluate it later. In your case, you can use `strrep(",", p)` to repeat "," p times, then use `str2expression()` to transform it into an expression that can be evaluated. If you put it in a function:

```
slice_first_dimension <- function(arr){
  p <- length(dim(Y))
  eval(str2expression(paste0("arr[1",strrep(",", p-1),"]")))
}

Y <- array(1:8, dim=c(2,2,2))
slice_first_dimension(Y)
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    5
#> [2,]    3    7
```

Comment: awesome! This answers my question. Question: what if I want to assign a value to the sub-array? I can't do
eval(str2expression(paste0("arr[1",strrep(",", p-1),"]"))) <- array(0,dim(Y)[-1])

Comment: I'd say either do it in 2 steps (`Y2  <- slice_first_dimension(Y); Y2[xx] <- yy` with appropriate xx and yy), or build an expression that does the transformation, like `my_operation <- paste0("Y[", strrep(xx),"] <- array(yy)"); eval(str2expression(my_operation))`

Comment: I see, this makes a lot of sense. Thank you!